# MaterialDesign: access and change ShadowDepth from code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I can create Card in materialDesign using below xaml code:

```
<materialDesign:Card materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth1" x:Name="btnUserAdd">
</materialDesign:Card>
```

How can I change "ShadowDepth" to "Depth2" in code below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like any other dependency property:

```
btnUserAdd.SetValue(ShadowAssist.ShadowDepthProperty, ShadowDepth.Depth2);
```

or since it is [an attached DP](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/ShadowAssist.cs#L42):

```
ShadowAssist.SetShadowDepth(btnUserAdd, ShadowDepth.Depth2);
```